# Summary table generation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to see data in a summary view like this:

[image]

I need help for a T-SQL script. Thank you.

Sorry for my little English.

Comment: Can you share what you've done so far?

Comment: This kind of thing would be best in the front end, especially if you need to have empty values in certain rows like this. It can of course be done in sql it is just kind of the wrong place. If you can post a sqlfiddle with some data we can help.

Comment: You want to look at doing a `Pivot`

Comment: Thank you all. I posted a fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbbf23/1

Answer (score 2):

This works:

[Setup]

```
CREATE TABLE #PaymentTable ( Id INT IDENTITY, AccountGroupId INT, AccountId INT, Payment INT )
INSERT INTO #PaymentTable ( AccountGroupId, AccountId, Payment ) 
SELECT 1, 1, 5 UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1, 5 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 2, 5 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 4, 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 5 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3, 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4, 5

CREATE TABLE #Group ( AccountGroupId INT, GroupName VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO #Group ( AccountGroupId, GroupName )
SELECT 1, 'Group 1' UNION Select 2, 'Group 2'

CREATE TABLE #Account ( AccountId INT, AccountName VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO #Account ( AccountId, AccountName )
SELECT 1, 'John' UNION Select 2, 'Edvard' UNION
SELECT 3, 'David' UNION SELECT 4, 'Jimi'
```

[Query]

```
SELECT
  [Group],
  Account,
  TotalPayment
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      #Group.AccountGroupId AS GroupId,
      GroupName AS [Group],
      '' AS Account,
      SUM( Payment ) AS TotalPayment,
      0 AS InnerOrder
    FROM
      #PaymentTable,
      #Group
    WHERE
      #Group.AccountGroupId = #PaymentTable.AccountGroupId
    GROUP BY
      #Group.AccountGroupId,
      #Group.GroupName
    UNION
    SELECT
      AccountGroupId AS GroupId,
      '' AS [Group],
      AccountName AS Account,
      SUM( Payment ) AS TotalPayment,
      1 AS InnerOrder
    FROM
      #PaymentTable,
      #Account
    WHERE
      #Account.AccountId = #PaymentTable.AccountId
    GROUP BY
      AccountGroupId,
      AccountName
  ) AS inner_query
ORDER BY
  GroupId,
  InnerOrder,
  Account
```

Comment: To other comments that suggested pivots or front-end dev. These are good possible solutions to certain situations, but I've come across environments where the data consumer was either too horrendous to properly display data in the way @phoenix requested (e.g. BIRT and it's Rhino/Javascript/Java-based hybrid scripting engine) or completely unreachable (e.g. a "dumb" reporting feature that only spits out excel spreadsheets based on the exact set it receives from the database). In other words, this specific request is valid and might require a direct solution rather than a work-around.

Comment: Thank you @Paurian. The solution is very handy for me.